# SVG in IMG tag rendering not as expected

Tags: image, svg

Just a quick one with a problem i'm having with custom SVG Icons.

We have used a vector icon set for one of our clients and we are using the icons on their website.

I have outputted the SVG's from illustrator and then linked to them on the website using a IMG tag. However the icons are rendering really weird. The edges look all wonky and not as they should be. I have pasted the code and a screenshot of the icon on the website.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

```
<img src="/assets/images/misc/why-icon-1.svg" class="img-fluid img-center overlayImage"/>

.overlayImage {
position: absolute;
top: 28%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
width: 77px;
```

}

[image: SVG Icon on the website]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out! For anyone else encountering the same problem here is the answer:

Basically when exporting a SVG from Illustrator you need to set the decimal places to a larger number. The number ranges from 1-7 the higher you go the better the SVG but the file size will also increase. I found 3 was a happy medium.

[image: Illustrator SVG Settings]